# Form button redirect

Tags: php, html

here is the site Iam building - http://dtech.id.lv/lat.php

Entered/generated code is passed to latreg.php on submit with $_SESSION

But after that I need that user is redirected to this latreg.php

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

The action property of your form should be used to redirect the user after the submission.

Does your code looks like: `<form name="myForm" method="POST" action="./latreg.php">`?

Comment: No it looks like <form method="POST"> Cus if I add action="./latreg.php" it doesn't run onClick= <?php $_SESSION['kods'] = $_POST['textField'] ?>

Comment: You can't use onClick like this. The PHP is server side, and Javascript (such as onClick) is client side. It means that when the page arrives on your browser, everything wich is written in PHP is already executed. You should read some more doc, or show some code if I misunderstood you.

Comment: Then use `action="yourscripage.php"`and after you executed what you want, call the `header()`function. E.G: `header('location:latreg.php');`.
I advice you to read some basics about PHP/JS Programming by the way...